# How to add an action button in Powerpoint that opens the file explorer?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am interested in creating an action button in my PPT presentation that can open the file explorer on mac or windows so that the user can insert a picture. Basically I have a mockup of a phone and I want to create a rectangle inside of it with an action button so the user can click on the button and the file explorer can open and the user can select a screenshot to put into the mockup. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I do not think this question fits the expertise of a Graphic Designer and better suited for a website like [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/). If this is even possible, then you most likely have to use a Macro.

Comment: Images can be changed easily by right-clicking the image and choosing "replace image". But I understand that a button would be more intuitive. And yes, you need a Macro, which can cause some other inconvenience like some antivirus warnings or something.